# Does JUnit 5 guarantee the happens-before relationship for ordered test methods?

Tags: java, concurrency, junit5

I sometimes order test methods using the following annotation: `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)`

Does JUnit 5 guarantee the [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) relationship for these? In other words are all changes by a test method visible to all subsequent test method?

Here is my concrete use case though I'm not sure if its considered good style:

I have an integration test that executes several steps: 1) connect to a server (i.e. create a connection object), 2) issue request1, 3) issue request2. The order of these requests is important. I split these steps into several JUnit test methods executed in order. Step 1) stores the connection object in a static field so it is accessible by steps 2) and 3). I was wondering if I have to make the connection object created by step 1) volatile or if JUnit guarantees its visibility in steps 2) and 3).

Comment: Is that a theoretical question or have you encountered a specific problem while executing tests in order?

Comment: @johanneslink I added my use case. I would also be interested to know if this considered bad style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JUnit 5 guarantees the happens-before-relationship in its default configuration because by default all tests of a class are executed sequentially by the same thread as documented [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution).